# class=ng-binding stops me from getting the textContent of an DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a Chrome extension and I need to get some information from the web page.
I am trying to access the text content of a `<strong class="ng-binding">Hello world</strong>` element with javascript, but I get an empty string, instead of "Hello world".
I have no problem accessing other elements' content in the DOM, which doesn't have this class attribute.

How can I get the data with javascrpt from that elements?

```
var Tags = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
for (var i = 0; i < Tags.length; i++) {
    //print the textContent;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Tags = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
for (var i = 0; i < Tags.length; i++) {
    //print the textContent;
 var text = angular.element(Tags[i]).text();
 console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. However this returns me "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined", perhaps I need to include something beforehand. Bare in mind that this code is in the content script of the extension.

Comment: I start realising what might be causing the issue - the data in those elements is not loaded at the time I am accessing it, although the DOM is fully loaded.